# Use current Subversion slave server as master server

Tags: svn, restore

My master SVN server is down and HDD has gone bad, fortunately though we have a slave server setup. I'm guessing this is a slave server since I get mails regarding sycn'ing complete on this server. I'm guessing this since I'm new to the company and there are no proper documentation on this. Been reading about this online and I have a hint this slave server can be made a master server and be used for further code commits and updates, below are the steps I've discovered towards this change,

1. Remove the svn:sync-* properties from revision 0 of the slave.
2. Change authz and hooks on the slave to what they used to be on the master.
3. Have everyone relocate their working copies to the new server.
4. Start syncing a new server so we have a slave just in case something goes wrong on the master.

Regarding 1) should I just use an `svn pdel --revprop -r 0 svn:PROPERTY` and delete below mentioned properties?

```
svn:sync-from-uuid
svn:sync-last-merged-rev
svn:date
svn:sync-from-url
```

Answer (score 0):

P.1 not needed really - they are just additional properties, nothing more

P.3 may not work, because master and slave may have different UUIDs and in this case relocate will fail (check with `svn info`)